# Why enclose variable names with '' in robotframework code

Tags: robotframework

Inside a .robot file of the robotframework I stumbled into a code in where variables are enclosed with ''.

For example:

```
IF  '${var_name}' == '${FALSE}'
        Return from keyword
END
```

Any idea how it is useful or if it is correct at all?

Sincerely

Answer (score 5):

This is covered in the section [Evaluation Expressions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions) in the documentation for the BuiltIn library.

In short, after the variables are substituted, the expression is evaluated by python and thus must be valid python syntax. In your case, if `${var_name}` contains something like "hello world", then the expression would end up being `if hello world == 'False'`, which is invalid python.

In the same documentation it mentions that you can use `$var_name` (without the curly braces) so that a variable is used in the generated python expression rather than the string representation of the variable.